# Hierarchical cumulative sum in sql query (id,parentId) structure

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, reporting, database-administration

I have two tables that I want to get all accounts and their Credit sum and Debit sum 
even parent records have to sum thier child values

I'm implementing Id ParentId Structure .

1- [AccountChart] Table with these fields :

```
Id smallint
ParentId smallint Null
AccountName nvarchar(100)
```

2- [Transaction] Table with these fields

```
AccountId smallInt
TransactionDate DateTime
Debit decimal(19,5)
Credit decimal(19,5)
```

here is what I tried

```
    Create table [AccountChart] (
    id int not null,
    parentId int null,
    AccountName nvarchar(100)

    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
      )

    Create table [TransactionData] (
    id int not null,
    TransactionDate DateTime not null,
    AccountId int not null,
    Credit decimal(19,5),
    Debit decimal(19,5)

    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
    )

    insert into [AccountChart] (id,parentId,AccountName) values (1,null,'level 0');
    insert into [AccountChart] (id,parentId,AccountName) values (2,1,'level 2');
    insert into [AccountChart] (id,parentId,AccountName) values (3,2,'level 3 - 1');
    insert into [AccountChart] (id,parentId,AccountName) values (4,2,'level 3 - 2 ');


    insert into [TransactionData] (id,TransactionDate,AccountId,Credit,Debit) values (1,'2020-03-17',3,1000.0,0.0)
    insert into [TransactionData] (id,TransactionDate,AccountId,Credit,Debit) values (2,'2020-03-17',3,0.0,1000.0)
    insert into [TransactionData] (id,TransactionDate,AccountId,Credit,Debit) values (3,'2020-03-17',4,4000.0,0.0)
    insert into [TransactionData] (id,TransactionDate,AccountId,Credit,Debit) values (4,'2020-03-17',3,6000.0,0.0)
    insert into [TransactionData] (id,TransactionDate,AccountId,Credit,Debit) values (5,'2020-03-17',4,3000.0,0.0)


    ;WITH cteBalances (AccountId, ParentId, Credit, Debit)
    AS (SELECT
      AccountChart.Id,
      AccountChart.ParentId,
      SUM([TransactionData].Credit) AS Credit,
      SUM([TransactionData].Debit) AS Debit
     FROM [TransactionData]
     INNER JOIN AccountChart ON ([TransactionData].AccountId = AccountChart.Id)
     GROUP BY AccountChart.Id,AccountChart.ParentId)

    SELECT
      AccountChart.id,
      AccountChart.ParentId,
      AccountChart.AccountName,
      cteBalances.Credit,
      cteBalances.Debit
    FROM  AccountChart 
    left JOIN cteBalances ON (AccountChart.ID = cteBalances.AccountID)
```

the problem that I couldn't bring the summary values for the parent records.

the results I get is :

```
id  ParentId    AccountName   Credit        Debit
1   NULL        level 0       NULL          NULL
2   1           level 2       NULL          NULL
3   2           level 3 - 1   7000.00000    1000.00000
4   2           level 3 - 2   7000.00000    0.00000
```

but I excpect to be calculate the childs in parent as this

```
id  ParentId    AccountName   Credit        Debit
1   NULL        level 0       14000.00000   1000.00000
2   1           level 2       14000.00000   1000.00000
3   2           level 3 - 1   7000.00000    1000.00000
4   2           level 3 - 2   7000.00000    0.00000
```

Comment: can you please provide some sample data and expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the technique of using Range Keys.  **If you have a slow moving hierarchy**, I would create a table to store these values

Just to expand, the range keys facilitate selection, and variable depth aggregation.

You may notice that the `SEQ` has an `Order by AccountName`.  In my GL systems, we have a column for presentation sequence.  This controls the order rather than ALPHA on name or significant digits on the account.

**Example**

```
Declare @Top  int         =  null   --<<  Sets top of Hier Try 2
Declare @Nest varchar(25) = '|---'  --<<  Optional: Added for readability

;with cteP as (
      Select Seq  = cast(10000+Row_Number() over (Order by AccountName) as varchar(500))
            ,ID
            ,ParentID 
            ,Lvl=1
            ,AccountName
      From   [AccountChart] 
      Where  IsNull(@Top,-1) = case when @Top is null then isnull(ParentID ,-1) else ID end
      Union  All
      Select Seq  = cast(concat(p.Seq,'.',10000+Row_Number() over (Order by r.AccountName)) as varchar(500))
            ,r.ID
            ,r.ParentID 
            ,p.Lvl+1
            ,r.AccountName
      From   [AccountChart] r
      Join   cteP p on r.ParentID  = p.ID)
     ,cteR1 as (Select *,R1=Row_Number() over (Order By Seq) From cteP)
     ,cteR2 as (Select A.ID,R2=Max(B.R1) From cteR1 A Join cteR1 B on (B.Seq like A.Seq+'%') Group By A.Seq,A.ID )
Select A.Lvl
      ,A.R1  
      ,B.R2
      ,A.ID
      ,A.ParentID 
      ,AccountName = max(Replicate(@Nest,A.Lvl-1) + A.AccountName)
      ,Credit      = sum(C.Credit)
      ,Debit       = sum(C.Debit)
 From cteR1 A
 Join cteR2 B on A.ID=B.ID
 Join (Select _R1=A.R1,B.* From cteR1 A Join [TransactionData] B on A.ID=B.AccountID ) C on (C._R1 between A.R1 and B.R2)
 Group By A.R1,B.R2,A.Lvl,A.ID,A.ParentID
 Order By A.R1
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but this solution doesn't provider the expected results and is not maintainable easily. can you make it more readable and clear.

Comment: @Shehab Corrected, In the final query/aggregation, I joined to ID rather than AccountID

Comment: It works. but when I tried it with my actual data it was very slow. Can we make it more faster or do it in a cleaner way ?

Comment: @Shehab What is slow... the hierarchy build or the aggregation?   How deep is your chart of accounts?    Indexes count; is the transaction table indexed?   I've used the range key technique for decades at tier-1 banks with TREMENDOUS performance on truly massive data (billions of rows).   Again, I suggest if you have a slow moving/changing hierarchy, store that with the range keys.  Then is becomes a small matter of aggregation between R1 and R2

Comment: The Aggregation I think it was very slow. it took 1 minute and 26 seconds to get the results. the transaction table I have has more than 1 million and half records.

Comment: @Shehab 1.5 minutes is way too long.  I would not tolerate that as well.  This is more or less a demonstration of the range keys.  Again, I would suggest saving your hierarchy to a table (with the range keys).  This technique will allow you to aggregate data to summary levels (i.e. levels 1 - 3) without having to go full depth/detail.  At the bank, we have dozens of hierarchies which server multiple masters:  Management Reporting, Regulatory Reporting, Selection Criteria and Processing.  I wish I could share the environment so you could witness the power and flexibilty.

Comment: It works. could someone help me with - if I've the Credit and debit on same table, how do I calculate the cumulative sum?